# Let $a, b, c,x$ be elements of a group $G$. In each of the following, solve for $x$ in terms of $a, b, c$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Just checking my work.

---

$axb =c.$

$(axb)a^{-1}b^{-1} = ca^{-1}b^{-1}$

$x = ca^{-1}b^{-1}$

---

$x^2b = xa^{-1}c$

$x^{-1}(x^2b) = (xa^{-1}c)x^{-1}$

$xb = a^{-1}c$

$x = a^{-1}b^{-1}c$

---

$x^2a = bxc^{-1}$ and $acx = xac.$

$(x^2a)x^{-1} = (bxc^{-1})x^{-1}$

$xa = bc^{-1}$

$(xa)c = (bc^{-1})c$

$acx = b$

$x = a^{-1}bc^{-1}$

---

$ax^2 = b$ and $x^3 = e.$

$(ax^2)x = bx$

$ae = bx$

$x = ab^{-1}$

---

$x^2 = a^2$ and $x^5 = e$

$(x^2)^2 = (a^2)^2$

$(x^4)x = a^4x$

$e = a^4x$

$(a^4)^{-1} = x$

---

$(xax)^3 = bx$ and $x^2a = (xa)^{-1}$

$((xax)^3)^{-2} = (bx)^{-2}$

$xax  = (bx)^{-2}$

$((xa)^{-1})^2 = ((bx)^{-2})^2$

$xa = 0$

$xaa^{-1} = 0a^{-1}$

$x = 0$

Comment: It would be helpful if you asked a question that could be answered instead of just posting a string of statements.

Comment: Question seems quite obvious to me: OP asks to check his work.

Comment: **Myself** is correct: the question is obvious. And downvoting a question that shows copious work certainly sends the wrong message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’re forgetting that the group operation need not be commutative: the order of the operands matters. In the first problem, for example, $(axb)a^{-1}b^{-1}$ does not simplify to $x$; in fact, it doesn’t simplify at all without further knowledge of the group in question. You need to multiply $axb$ on the *left* by $a^{-1}$ and on the *right* by $b^{-1}$:

$$a^{-1}(axb)b^{-1}=(a^{-1}a)x(bb^{-1})=x\;,$$

so $x=a^{-1}cb^{-1}$.

You’ve made similar errors in the second and third problems. The fourth is correct, as is the fifth, though its answer could better be expressed as $x=a^{-4}$. The last is wrong: $(y^3)^{-2}=y^{-6}$, not $y$.

Comment: Would this be correct for $(2)$: $x^{-1}(x^2b) = x^{-1}(xa^{-1}c) \to (x^{-1}x^2)b = (x^{-1}x)a^{-1}c \to xb = ea^{-1}c \to x = a^{-1}cb^{-1}$?

Comment: @AbstraktAlgebra: Yes, that’s correct.

Comment: @ Brian M. Scott, here's my attempt at $(3)$, please see if that's correct: $ (x^2a)c = (bxc^{-1})c \to xxac = bx \to xacx = bx \to xac = b \to x = b(ac)^{-1}$.

Comment: @AbstraktAlgebra: Yes, though you can simplify it one step further: $(ac)^{-1}=c^{-1}a^{-1}$ (note the reversal of order), so $x=bc^{-1}a^{-1}$.

Comment: @  Brian M. Scott, here's number $6$: $((xax)^3)^{-2} = (bx)^{-2} \to xax = x^{-2}b^{-2} \to x(xax) = x(x^{-2}b^{-2}) \to (xxa)x = (xx^{-2})b^{-2} \to (a^{-1}x^{-1})x = (x^{-1})b^{-2} \to (a^{-1}(x^{-1}x) = (x^{-1})b^{-2} \to a^{-1} = (x^{-1})b^{-2} \to xa^{-1} = b^{-2} \to x = b^{-2}a$

Comment: @AbstraktAlgebra: No, you’re still making the same mistake right at the beginning: $((xax)^3)^{-2}=(xax)^{-6}$, not $xax$. You need to expand $(xax)^3$ to $xax^2ax^2ax$ and use the fact that $x^2a=(xa)^{-1}=a^{-1}x$.

Comment: @  Brian M. Scott, how about now?

$xax^2ax^2ax = bx \to xa(a^{-1}x^{-1})x^2ax = bx \to xxax = bx \to (a^{-1}x^{-1})x = bx \to a^{-1} = bx \to x = a^{-1}b^{-1}.$

Comment: @AbstraktAlgebra: You were doing fine until the last step, where you forgot about the order again: if $a^{-1}=bx$, you have to multiply on the *left* to get rid of the $b$, so you end up with $x=b^{-1}a^{-1}$.

Comment: @ Brian M. Scott, I see. Thank you very much!

Comment: @AbstraktAlgebra: You’re very welcome!